# Querying questions and listing them with its answer options not working in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3

I am working on a multiple choice quiz app in Laravel 5.3.I have three tables:

```
questions table
id ->pk
question
is_active

answers table
id ->pk
question_id - fk references questions@id
answer

correct_answer table
id ->pk
answer_id ->references answers@id
```

Now I want to select each question from questions table
with its corresponding answers from answers table. This is how I want to list the result:

```
question one
answer 1
answer 2
answer 3
answer 4

question two
answer 1
answer 2
answer 3
answer 4
```

I have tried this:

```
 $questions = DB::table("questions")  
                    ->select("question")  
                   ->join("answers","answers.question_id",
                        "=","questions.id")
                        ->where("questions.is_active",1)
                        ->groupBy("questions.question")
                        ->get();
```

But this query gives me the following results:

```
question one
answer 1
question two
answer 1
```

Only the first option for each question is returned when each question has 4 options in the answers table

```
id  question_id answer
1   2           answer 1
2   2           answer 2
3   2           answer 3
4   2           answer 4
5   3           answer 1
6   3           answer 2
7   3           answer 3
8   3           answer 4
```

I have also tried this but getting the same results:

```
$questions = DB::table('questions')
        ->leftjoin('questions','question_id',
            'answers.question_id','=','questions.id')
        ->select('*')                    
        ->where('questions.is_active','=',1)
        ->groupBy('question')       
        ->get();
```

Question model hasMany to Answer model. I have set this in the model. Please help me solve this. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use **Eloquent ORM** rather than using query builder.

I'm not sure that you have set proper relationships in the models or not.

So let's start from scratch.

Each question has multiple answers. So relationship will be **One-to-Many**.

**Question model**

```
class question extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the answers of a question
     */
    public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Answer');
    }
}
```

**Answer Model** (On if you want to get the question of an answer - ignore otherwise)

```
class Answer extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the question of an answer
     */
    public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Question');
    }
}
```

**In controller action**

```
$questions = Question::with('answers')->get();
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks it works. My relationships was quite fine. What I lacked was the eloquent approach. Thanks very much.